# Energy estimate in Evans PDE book

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, estimation

Before Theorem 6 in Chapter 7.4 in Evans' PDE book Evans claims that there exists $\beta > 0$ such that
$$
\beta\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 \leq B[u,u]\,, \quad \forall u \in H_0^1(\Omega)\,.
$$
From how it's stated I get the vibe that this should be trivial but for some reason I can't figure out the reasoning.

Here $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is the closure of smooth compactly supported functions in $H^1(\Omega)$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, bounded, and has smooth boundary.

$B$ is the bilinear form associated with a hyperbolic operator $\partial_t^2 + L$ where
$$
Lu = -\sum_{i,j=1}^n (a^{ij}(x,t) u_{x_i})_{x_j} + c(x,t) u
$$
($c \geq 0$ and $a^{ij} = a^{ji}$, I guess $a^{ij}$ and $c$ are continuously differentiable too, but he's not very clear with his assumptions) and thus
$$
B[u,v] = \int_\Omega \left( \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij}(x,t) u_{x_i} v_{x_j} + c(x,t) uv \right) \, dx\,.
$$
Hyperbolcity of $\partial_t^2 + L$ means that there exists $\theta > 0$ such that
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij} \xi_i \xi_j \geq \theta |\xi|^2
$$
for all $\xi = (\xi_1, ..., \xi_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I think the assumption $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ hints towards integration by parts or the Poincaré inequality ($\|u\|_{L^2} \leq C \|Du\|_{L^2}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

The hyperbolicity implies
$$
\theta \int_\Omega |Du|^2 \, dx \leq \int \sum_{i,j} a^{ij} u_i u_j \, dx = B[u,u] - \int_\Omega c u^2 \, dx \leq B[u,u]\,,
$$
since $c \geq 0$.

For $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ the Poincaré inequality implies that there exists $C \geq 0$ such that
$$
\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 = \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \|Du\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \leq (C+1)\|Du\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\,.
$$
Combining these we get
$$
\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 \leq \frac{C+1}{\theta} \theta \|Du\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \leq \frac{C+1}{\theta} B[u,u]\,.
$$
So we may choose $\beta = \frac{\theta}{C+1}$.